# MySQL "Like 'text%'" is Fast, but "NOT Like 'text%'" is Slow

Tags: mysql, wildcard, sql-like

I have a 21-column table with about 16M rows in it, and no fields have significant amounts of data in them.

This query finishes in a few milliseconds:

```
SELECT * FROM TestTable where str1 like 'UnitTest%' order by Id DESC LIMIT 100;
```

Most of the records in this table (all but 30 of the 16M) match that query, and it returns the first 100 matching rows almost immediately.

This query ("NOT like" instead of "like") returns the 30 rows that do NOT match the above query, as expected, but it takes 4 minutes to do it.

```
SELECT * FROM TestTable where str1 NOT like 'UnitTest%' order by Id DESC LIMIT 100;
```

I have a BTREE index on str1, and then added a FULLTEXT index on str1 per some other threads in a failed attempt to help the situation.

Queries without like, and both "like" and "not like" queries *without* wildcards (exact matches) run fast, too.

I thought that *without a **leading** wildcard*, MySQL could use indexes to find the target records quickly, but that doesn't appear to be happening.

Any ideas on what I can do to make this kind of query work better are appreciated.

Comment: Full-text indexes don't help with `LIKE`, they're only used for `MATCH`

Comment: I think this is just the way indexes work. The index is useful for matching prefixes, because you just walk down the B-tree for each character, and then return everything below that node. But `NOT LIKE` doesn't work the same way, because it's everything else.

Comment: What if you convert it to two ranges? (Something like `where (str1 < 'UnitTest'  or str1 > 'UnitTestZZ' )`)?

Comment: @Barmar - It's not character by character; the work is done with full strings.

Comment: @MartinSmith - Then `OR` becomes the performance killer.

Comment: A guess:  MySQL's Optimizer blindly assumes that `NOT` is unlikely to deserve any optimization.  (I failed to find a reasonable table on my machine that would be used to replicate your finding; the "NOT" part was too big.)

Comment: @RickJames in that case UNION ALL can replace OR